# Amending existing plugins to match Qgis 2.16+ fTools removal

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, development, ftools

Part-time development started about a year ago to create an add-on for Qgis.  Many of this plugins capabilities are written with fTools commands.

I am wondering if there is a recommended document to help developers migrate syntax to the new processing functions included with 2.16+.

Although fTools is still available through the *Plugin Manager*, rewriting the plugin is best for legacy with the Qgis programs future.

Comment: How were you calling the ftools commands? They aren't part of the public api...

Comment: The most common call in use was; qgsLayerRef = ftools_utils.getMapLayerByName(unicode('legend layer name')) .  In this particular case, would it be best to use the; layerRefs = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("legend layer name(s) in question")?

Comment: Yes - that's correct. If you have other calls you were using from ftools then can you post them too and I'll advise on possible replacements?